# How to handle singular resources with RESTAdapter

Tags: rest, ember.js, ember-data

How are singular resources handled in ember-data? Say I have the following RESTful routes:

```
GET /cart
POST /cart
UPDATE /cart
DELETE /cart
```

ember-data expects `find()` to return an array, plus it automatically tries to pluralize any url I pass to my model. What is the best way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 7):

There are a number of things you can do here.

The `RESTAdapter` calls pluralize, which either adds an "s" to the end of the name, or looks up the name in the plurals hash if it exists.  Assuming your DS.Model is `App.Cart`.

https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest_adapter.js#L209

```
DS.RESTAdapter.create({
  plurals: {
    cart: 'cart'
  }
});
```

If your URL scheme is very different and requires some further logic, you can actually override the buildURL function.

https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest_adapter.js#L288

```
DS.RestAdapter.create({
  buildURL: function() {
    return "/always_this"
  })
});
```

Comment: Overriding the buildURL function will apply to all models, though, right? What about my non-singular models? Also, even if I change the plurals, `find()` (without arguments) expects an array of objects, so that won't work. And if I pass a fake id to find, then I have to modify my server routes to accept an id argument (`/cart/:fake_id`) only to disregard it completely. It just seems too hacky for something so common and simple.

Comment: Build URL can do something like this: ``if (record.get('singularResouce') { ... } else { this._super.apply(this, arguments); }``. The (...) can be your own singular building URL function, and your singular models will have ``DS.Model.extend({ singularResouce: true })``.

Comment: You can even do something snazzy like call ``buildUrl`` again, but pass in undefined as the id.

Comment: Yeah, buildURL won't work for another reason: no actual objects are passed into it, just a string. record == 'cart'. So I can't check it for any properties (`get('singularResource')`)

Comment: ``App.Cart.reopenClass({ singularRecourse: true });`` and then  ``App.get(record + '.singularRecourse');`` You get the idea. Play with it, it will work. Let us know what you find.

Comment: There is also rootForType's ``root.type.url``. While this won't solve your problem, it is worth noting to others that is is another way to get more naming control: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest_adapter.js#L214

Comment: Yeah. I'll play around with it for a while and post what I come up with. Thanks for the help.

Comment: With new version of Ember data this does no longer work. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/21839261/2049986, this does still work.

Answer (score 3):

So, I found [this pull request](https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/58) on github. It's 8 months old, so won't work due to added complexity since then, but I've implemented the workaround suggested like so:

```
App.store = DS.Store.create({
  revision: 4,
  adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create({
    plurals: {
      'cart': 'cart'
    }
  })
});

App.Cart.reopenClass({
  find: function () {
    this._super("singleton");
  }
});
```

On my server (I'm using rails), I have to add the following to my routes:

```
get "cart/:ignored" => "carts#show"
```

Then I have to add the following to `CartSerializer` (using [active_model_serializers](https://github.com/josevalim/active_model_serializers) gem):

```
attributes :id
def id
  "singleton"
end
```

This is necessary, because, apparently, if the id in the json response doesn't match the id requested from find() (`singleton` in this case), then ember won't load the data into the model.

Now, this obviously isn't the ideal solution, but until ember-data adds support for it, it seems like the least painful way to go.

By the way, I filed [an issue](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/393) to add support.

Comment: I tried implementing this solution and it works on initial load...but once I navigate to another tab and then back to the singular resource tab, the api endpoint doesn't get called again. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I got this working in Ember 1.9. First I read [this section](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/setting-up-a-controller/) of the guide. At the very bottom it explains how to override an adapter for just one model.

```
App.CartAdapter = App.ApplicationAdapter.extend {
  pathForType: ->
    'cart'
}
```

The pathForType function is where the pluralization happens (at least in the RESTAdapter which I am using) so none of the other functionality of the adapter gets affected (like host, or namespace).

Answer (score 1):

Just to share a more complete solution which is working for me - extend your app's ApplicationRouter (which itself extends DS.RESTAdapter).

```
App.CartAdapter = App.ApplicationAdapter.extend({
    pathForType: function(type) {
        return 'cart';
    }
});
```

Next, define your resource in App.Router.map:

```
this.resource('cart');
```

Finally, pass an empty string as the id in your route. This is what allows the URL to be generated without an id.

```
App.CartRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model : function(params) {
        return this.store.find('cart', '');
    }
});
```