# How to run a function when Ember finished loading for the first time

Tags: javascript, ember.js, node-webkit

Hi i'm writing a simple ember app that I run within a node-webkit app, now I would like to run:

`require("nw.gui").Window.get().show();`

right after Ember finished loading and had rendered the index view, but just once, not if you've just navigated to `/`.

I've tried this:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller) {
    require("nw.gui").Window.get().show();
  }
});
```

But this executes on each navigation to `/`

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Ember.Application` has a [ready event](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Application.html#event_ready). That could match your needs.

You can use it like this:

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create({
    ready: function () {
        alert('Application ready!');
    }
});
```