# ember data no ID in model undefined

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, django-rest-framework

i currently have this as my model

`GalacticEmber.Testdata = DS.Model.extend({
      username: DS.attr('string'),
      phone: DS.attr(),
      last: DS.attr('string'),
      first: DS.attr('string')
      });`

and this is my route

```
GalacticEmber.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
model: function(){
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
        testdatum: this.store.find('testdata'),

    });
},
setupController: function(controller, model){
    controller.set('content', model.testdatum);
}
});
```

but when i navigate to my page i get this error??

"Error while loading route: undefined "

i can navigate to my site in site.com/api/testdatum (and this is the result django REST)

```
{
"testdata": [
    {
        "username": "bba1", 
        "phone": 55522114, 
        "last": "abbbla", 
        "first": "bob"
    }, 
    {
        "username": "ema1", 
        "phone": 9998887765, 
        "last": "hobart", 
        "first": "johnston"
    }
]
}
```

i know there is no "id" because it is comming from a NoSQL database. So i also have this line in my models.js file

```
GalacticEmber.TestdataSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
primaryKey: 'username'
});
```

stack trace for the console error::

```
Error while loading route: undefined ember.js:3285
logToConsole ember.js:3285
defaultActionHandlers.error ember.js:33921
triggerEvent ember.js:33996
trigger ember.js:32823
Transition.trigger ember.js:32044
handleError ember.js:33157
invokeCallback ember.js:9427
publish ember.js:9097
publishRejection ember.js:9525
DeferredActionQueues.flush ember.js:5650
Backburner.end ember.js:5741
Backburner.run ember.js:5780
Ember.run ember.js:6181
hash.error ember-data.js:8671
fire jquery.min.js:3048
self.fireWith jquery.min.js:3160
done jquery.min.js:8237
callback
```

what am i missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace for the error?

Comment: could you return testdatas as the root key ?

Comment: added in stacktrace and i did and the error was it was looking for testdatum

Comment: Specify the pluralization of the model in your Adapter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10875285/where-do-i-specify-the-pluralization-of-a-model-in-ember-data.

Answer (score 0):

```
'GalacticEmber.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
      return Ember.RSVP.hash({
    testdatum: this.store.find('testdata'),

    });
 },
 setupController: function(controller, model){
controller.set('content', model.testdatum);
 }}
 );'
```

just try

```
 `GalacticEmber.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
 model: function(){
    return this.store.findAll('testdata'),

});
 },
 setupController: function(controller, model){
controller.set('content', model.testdatum);
}
 });`
```

i don't know why you try to surround this in Promise, it's promise by default.

Comment: because i have other models i am using in this view. They work fine but are comming from a standard SQL database.

Comment: try to use primaryKey: '_id' instead username. I think in mongo DB _id was primery key by default but i'm not sure